# Where can I find an accurate map of Earth for a real-time third-person game?

Tags: terrain, heightmap

I want to create a game that will allow the player to move to any place on Earth. The game will not be first-person, but it will be possible to zoom in quite close nonetheless. What I am lacking is an accurate height-map of the planet. Textures such as albedo, specular or normal would also be very helpful.

I don't know if such textures exist, but an "accurate" height-map should have a resolution of at most a few meters.

The textures do not have to be 100% real. Some parts can be procedurally generated, as long as they look "realistic".

Comment: Have you tried NASA? Not sure of the resolution (so this is a comment rather than an answer) but here looks a good place to start: https://visibleearth.nasa.gov/images/73934/topography

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NASA has your back with the NASA Earth Observing System: https://eospso.nasa.gov/
The project has topography and albedo images of earth: https://visibleearth.nasa.gov/collection/1484/blue-marble

Comment: Thank you for answering so quickly. This does look really promising. I will have to check the resolution of these maps.